# WCF Initiation is taking too much time

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0

WCF service is taking around 5-6 seconds for first request there after all call execute very fast.
below is the client side configuration for my WCF service.

Using IIS hosting.

```
        WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
        binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        binding.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        binding.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        binding.AllowCookies = false;
        binding.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
        binding.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard;

        binding.MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Mtom; 

        binding.TextEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        binding.UseDefaultWebProxy = true;
        binding.Name = "BasicHttpBinding_ILearningService";


        binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;              
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
        binding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.None;
        binding.Security.Transport.Realm = "";
```

Server side configuration

```
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="LearningServiceServiceBehavior" name="LearningService">
    <host>

      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="https://xxxxx/LearningService.svc" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity" contract="ILearningSuiteService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
     </endpoint>

    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="TransportSecurity" messageEncoding="Mtom" sendTimeout="00:1:00" openTimeout="00:2:00">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="LearningServiceServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetEnabled="false" httpGetUrl="http://xxxxxxx/Metadata" httpsGetUrl="https://xxxxxxxx/Metadata" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: Are you creating the service and then making the first call right after? The problem may be that you have to wait for the service to be created before you can make any calls. Perhaps you should do this in initialization so that when you make the first call the service has already been created.

Comment: Yes, I am creating the web service and right after making first call. My requirement is like that. As soon program starts it request WCF service to get the data. Is there any way to improve this time lag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other issue you may be see is that as you are using transport security you are doing certificate validation on the client each time you create a new proxy. Is it possible the certificate validation is expensive, say, due to the revocation list for the certificate not being available in a timely fashion?

Try turning off security and see if that changes the behavior

Comment: it is true that certificate validation is expensive & due to this it is taking long time to execute my request. But now the question is how to improve it because SSL is my primary requirement.

Comment: What are you using SSL for - purely encryption or to validate the server identity as well?

Comment: I am using it for purely encryption.

Comment: In that case you can turn off certificate validation to reduce the overhead

Answer (score 2):

Although not completely definite it looks like you are IIS hosting (I say not definite because baseAddresses are not specified by you in IIS hosting, rather the actual .svc file is the base address for the service)

Assuming you are IIS hosting are you seeing the spin up time for the worker process? Depending on which version of Windows you are using you could use Windows Server AppFabric to autostart the service before the first request

Comment: Whenever I make first call from client it take 5-6 seconds, not the first web services call to server. So if I restart client application it again takes 5-6 second for first call.

Answer (score 1):

The first time you make the call, the client sets up the connection to the server and the server does necessary authentication, this can take some time.
And based on what I found in my project, the WCF serialization can take much time in the first time if your contract is huge. After that, the serialization can be much quicker.

Comment: Does this serialization takes more time SSL, if yes how can we reduce it? I am returning dataset from the WCF method, that dataset contains 100 recirds and if 4-6 K in size.